# How to sort Wordpress title-tag parts?

Tags: wordpress, title

I need to change the position of my title parts. Now my homepage renders:

"blogname separator description"

And I would like to place the blogname at the end:

"description separator blogname"

My theme supports `title-tag` and I read that it has 3 filters, which are:

`add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`

- `pre_get_document_title` short-circuits `wp_get_document_title()` if it returns anything other than an empty value.
- `document_title_separator` filters the separator between title parts.
- `document_title_parts` filters the parts that make up the document title, passed in an associative array.

How to use them in order to change the position of the title parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change title part on homepage or front-page WordPress

*@retroriff*, if you need re-order of `title` and `tagline` as part of wp title on homepage, you can use filter [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/), and fire with a function. First, we need to unset them, then re-build as order. Here my sample approach:

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'wp36469459_document_title_parts', 1, 1 );
function wp36469459_document_title_parts( $title )
{
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
       
        //we unset title and tagline
        unset( $title['title'], $title['tagline'] );

        //re-build and order
        $title['tagline'] = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        $title['title']   = get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
    }
    
    return $title;
}
```

OR

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'wp36469459_document_title_parts', 1, 1 );
function wp36469459_document_title_parts( $title )
{
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        $_title   = $title['title'];
        $_tagline = $title['tagline'];
        unset( $title['title'], $title['tagline'] );
        $title['tagline'] = $_tagline;
        $title['title']   = $_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

You can tweak the code as suit your need.

Comment: It works like a charm. The unset() was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to reverse the title parts (for the home page), then this works:

```
function theme_document_title_parts($title) {
  return (is_home() || is_front_page()) ? array_reverse($title) : $title;
}

add_filter('document_title_parts', 'theme_document_title_parts');
```